# How to solve $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-2x-x^2}}\,dx}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-2x-x^2}}\,dx}$$

I tried to do it by substitution with no sucess. Anyone can solve it?

Comment: *Hint:* Note that $3 - 2x - x^2 = 2^2 - (x+1)^2$

Comment: Hint for every integral of this type http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Comment: Thanks prometheus21, that link is being very usefull to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you should think of instantly when you see a thing like that is that **completing the square** is the standard method in algebra for reducing a problem involving a quadratic polynomial with a first-degree term to a problem involving a quadratic polynomial with **no** first-degree term.

In this case $3-2x-x^2 = 4 - (x+1)^2 = 4-u^2$.  Now you have a constant term, $4$, and a quadratic term, $-u^2$.

Next: Do you have
\begin{align}
\sqrt{a^2-u^2} \\[6pt]
\text{or }\sqrt{u^2-a^2} \\[6pt]
\text{or }\sqrt{u^2+a^2} & {}\quad \text{?}
\end{align}
Each yields to a different trigonometric subsitution.

Comment: I'll keep in mind the "completing the square" mindset, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT:** Complete the square $$3 - 2x - x^2 = 4-1-2x-x^2 =2^2 - (x+1)^2$$

Then put $(x+1) = 2\sin \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Completing the square and using the substitution $u=x+1$ gives us

\begin{equation*}
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-(x+1)^2}}dx=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-u^2}}du=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{4}}}.
\end{equation*}

Using the substitution $s=\frac{u}{2}$ gives

\begin{equation*}
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}=\sin^{-1}(s)+C.
\end{equation*}

Substituting back $s=\frac{u}{2}$ and $u=x+1$ gives the result.